# How to use robot framework with python in eclipse and How to run the Robot framework tests in eclipse using python interpreters?

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have installed robot framework plugin into my eclipse.
I have added python plugins and interpreter in the path, python files are executing successfully.
I have added built-in library index file in the project, created robot text file and i want to execute the test but i right click on the test and try to run as, it is not giving the run configurations. I tried F9 for execution but it is not working.
I think there is the separate set up required for running the robot tests in eclipse.
my project we don't have access to Maven and client doesn't want Maven.
Please let me know how to execute the robot tests in eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does eclipse crash? Do your tests run but fail? Do you get an error? What error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use RED (Robotframework Editor), an extension for Eclipse available in the Eclipse Marketplace. Once you installed, simply go to "Run -> Run configurations..." and configure a run profile under "Robot". Eclipse will execute the following command on your test:

```
/usr/bin/python -m robot.run
```

You can check the logs in the "Message Log" view, and test results in the "Execution View".

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I setup my Eclispe to run Pybot for Windows 7.  You have to setup "External Tools", I don't have a high enough reputation to post images so see the steps below.  Once you've setup an external tools configuration you'll use "Run-->External Tools-->Pybot".

HTH,

From the Eclipse tool bar:

1. Run-->External Tools-->External Tools Configurations...
2. From the "External Tools configurations" pop-up select "Program", then press the New button
3. Fill in the following setting on the definition screen:

   - Name:  Pybot (or a name of your choosing)
   - Location:  C:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat (path to your pybot.bat file)
   - Working Directory:  C:\workspace_42  (your Eclipse workspace)
   - Arguments:  "${selected_resource_loc}"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute Python's flavour of Robot Framework you must use either command line or the [Robot IDE (RIDE)](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-ride/). To run your tests from the command line you must:
1. Open the terminal
2. Navigate to the appropriate directory
3. Use the `pybot` command and then specify the folder/file containing your tests

eg.

```
pybot mytestfolder
pybot myfirsttest.txt
```

Comment: Your statement is partially true, but a bit misleading. You can run tests from many different editors, not just RIDE. In all cases, both other editors and with RIDE itself, ultimately the tests are run with the command line test runner.