# robot framework output and result file path & name configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, robotframework

I'm using robot framework with eclipse to test the scripts.
Every time I run a test it overwrites old result and output file. How & what configuration must be done in eclipse that instead of overwriting the output & result file, it always generates a new output & result files?

This is achievable by command line but i want to know how it can be configured in eclipse

Comment: What are you actually asking for - the robot arguments that will allow you to set these, or the exact steps & places in Eclipse to put them in?

Comment: the robot arguments that will allow you to set these, so every test case executed generates a new output & result file rather than overwriting these

Comment: If you just need the robot arguments, they are all documented in the user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the generated statistics files are controlled with these command line options:

- `--output`, for the detailed xml file which default name is "output.xml",
- `--report`, for the summary html file which default name is "report.html",
- `--log`, for the detailed html file which default name is "log.html".

On top of that, there is an [option `-T` or `--timestamp`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#timestamping-output-files), which when used will put a time stamp in the file's name, just before the extension.
With it the file will be called (as an example) "output-20080604-163225.xml" - which looks like precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: From the question: "This is achievable by command line but i want to know how it can be configured in eclipse". :)

Comment: @BenceKaulics From the answer given to the first comment - _"What are you actually asking for?"_ - _"the **robot arguments that** will allow you to set these, so every test case executed generates a new output"_  ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: Many Thanks! 
How to configure below command in eclipse while executing tests ?
robot --timestampoutputs --log mylog.html --report NONE tests.robot

Comment: How do you start a run currently? Pass these arguments on top of your current ones.

Comment: No, I pass this on command line & it generates new files as per timestamp & I'm looking forward to configure same in eclipse so that whenever test is executed it generates new output files

Comment: There are quite a few resources how to configure Eclipse for RF. Here are a couple from SO itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27697865/3446126 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/49654291/3446126 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/47682762/3446126

Answer (score 0):

if you want to configure it using eclipse.

1. right click red.xml
2. click run as configurations
3. type in 'Additional Robotframework arguments' --timestampoutputs --log mylog.html --report NONE tests.robot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdCSa.png)